# Using *ngFor to display Angular 12 class inside a class

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I've created an Angular class, Course, which has another Angular class, Student, as one of it's properties. Objects of each class are served up RESTfully from my backend application (which works fine, tested w/ Postman). I'm trying to display a table listing each course and student in my template; however, the browser errors out with the following: 'Student | undefined' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.

Here's the code:

course.ts

```
import { Student } from './student';

export class Course {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    department?: string;
    student?: Student
}
```

student.ts

```
export class Student {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    dob?: Date;
    age?: number;
}
```

course-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.css']
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {

  courses?: Course[];

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCourses();
  }

  private getCourses() {
    this.courseService.getCourseList().subscribe(data => {
      this.courses = data;
      console.log("Course List", this.courses);
    });
  }
}
```

`console.log("Course List", this.courses);` from `getCourses()` above displays the JSON objects I'm expecting (example):

```
0:
   department: "FACS"
   id: 401
   instructor: null
   name: "Underwater Basket Weaving"
   student:
      age: 43
      dob: "23 JAN 1977"
      email: "arrowGuy77@nevermisses.net"
      id: 103
      name: "Hawk Eye"
```

course.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Course } from './course';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseService {

  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/courses";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getCourseList(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Course[]>(this.baseURL);
  }
}
```

course-list.component.html

```
<h2>Course List</h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">
            <td>{{course.id}}</td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.department}}</td>
            <td *ngFor = "let student of course.student">
                <p>{{student.name}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The second *ngFor is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

student property in the class Course, not a list so to solve this error you need to change

```
<h2>Course List</h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">
            <td>{{course.id}}</td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.department}}</td>
            <td *ngFor = "let student of course.student">
                <p>{{student.name}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

to be

```
<h2>Course List</h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">
            <td>{{course.id}}</td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.department}}</td>
            <td>
                <p>{{course.student.name}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Course.student is not an array, it's an object, but you're trying to put it inside an ngFor (that is something that should iterate over a list/array).

If all you want to do is display the name, you can do as simple as:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">
  <td>{{course.id}}</td>
  <td>{{course.name}}</td>
  <td>{{course.department}}</td>
  <td>{{course?.student?.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `?.` operator makes sure no errors are thrown if `course.student` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please make one thing clear:

- Are you going to have a possibility to have multiple students?

or

- Each course may have only one student?

**Multiple students** - you must have property `student?: Student` as `students?: Student[]`
So this structure

```
0:
   department: "FACS"
   id: 401
   student:
      age: 43
      name: "Hawk Eye"
```

you shall redo into

```
0:
   department: "FACS"
   id: 401
   students: [
      {
      age: 43
      name: "Hawk Eye"
      },
      {
      age: 33
      name: "Other guy"
      },
      ...
```

This you need to iterate students with `<td *ngFor = "let student of course.students">`

**Next, if you have only one student** per Course, you don't have to use *ngFor at all.
For each course iteration just render course.student name and other info using first *ngFor construction `<tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">`

```
<tr *ngFor = "let course of courses">
            <td>{{course.id}}</td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.department}}</td>
            <td>
                <p>{{course.student.name}}</p>
                <p>{{course.student.age}}</p>
                <p>{{course.student.email}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
```